# Multiplying a square array and row array with nested for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to multiply a square array and a row array with nested for loops but I am running into errors such as `object of type numpy.int64' has no len().`

I need to be able to calculate the product with two nested for loops but I am unsure where I can change my code to optimise and fix my errors.

```
def matvec_row_variant_scalar(A,x):
    product_array = np.zeros((len(A),len(A)),dtype=int)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(x[0])):
            for k in range(len(x)):
                product_array[i][j] += A[i][k] * x[k][j]
    return product_array

# Test arrays
square_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
row_array = np.array([2,2])
matvec_row_variant_scalar(square_array,row_array)
```

Comment: Since you're already using `numpy` what's wrong with `numpy.multiply`?

Comment: I was told to use nested for loops as part of my task but I can't figure out how to accomplish that without getting errors.

Comment: on which line you got error

Comment: So is this a homework problem and they want you to re-implement your own multiplication?

Comment: Yeah, it's for homework. They want me to multiply a square matrix by a row matrix with nested for loops.

Comment: Please provide a complete example that we can run on our computer in order to reproduce the error. So add two sample for `A` and `x`.

Comment: I've updated the code with some test arrays that I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Thanks for the help from everyone. Here's the code for anyone interested:

```
import numpy as np

def matvec_row_variant_scalar(A,x):
    product_array = np.zeros((len(A),len(A)),dtype=int)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            product_array[i][j] += x[i] * A[i][j]
        column_sum = product_array.sum(axis=0)
    return column_sum
    
square_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
row_array = np.array([2,2])
matvec_row_variant_scalar(square_array,row_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code has two problems.

1. On the second for loop you used `len(x[0])`. as declaration x is 1D array and then x[0] is an Integer and calculating length on integer will thrown type error .

   print(len(2)) #TypeError: object of type int has no len()
2. On `product_array[i][j] += A[i][k] * x[k][j]`, again you should consider x is 1D!

Here is your fixed code.

```
import numpy as np
def matvec_row_variant_scalar(A,x):
    product_array = np.zeros((len(A),len(A)),dtype=int)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            for k in range(len(x)):
                product_array[i][j] += A[i][k] * x[j]
    return product_array

# Test arrays
square_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
row_array = np.array([2,2])
matvec_row_variant_scalar(square_array,row_array)
```

The returned Result is

```
array([[ 6,  6],
       [14, 14]])
```